# how to install bs-stepper with webpacker in rails 6?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, turbolinks, webpacker

I have installed it using `yarn add bs-stepper`

and I have load the library into my `environment.js`

```
const { environment } = require("@rails/webpacker");

const webpack = require("webpack");

environment.plugins.append(
  "Provide",
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    Popper: ["popper.js", "default"],
    Stepper: "bs-stepper",
  })
);

module.exports = environment;
```

and I already make an instance of it on my `pack/application.js`

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs";
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks";
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage";
import "channels";
import "bootstrap";
import "../stylesheets/application";
require("admin-lte");
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all";

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  var stepper = new Stepper($(".bs-stepper")[0]);
});

Rails.start();
Turbolinks.start();
ActiveStorage.start();

require("trix");
require("@rails/actiontext");
import "controllers";
```

but the code is not working when I click this button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="stepper.next()">Next</button>
```

I got this error

```
(index):223 Uncaught ReferenceError: stepper is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):223)
```

I think its because my html is cannot find `stepper` that declared in `application.js`

Comment: Did you mean to use `new Stepper(...)`?

Comment: yeah I have corrected that somehow my page is cannot find `stepper`  that declared in `application.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is the way I set the instance of `Stepper`

I need to explicitly attach it to the `window`'s variable like this

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  window.stepper = new Stepper($(".bs-stepper")[0]);
});
```